# Laravel images are not displayed

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

I want to display the images in my view. The images are located in public folder in folder name **img**.

I've tried following solutions:

```
 <img href="{{URL::to('img/zajeciadodatkowe.png')}}" alt="Image" height="200" width="200">

 <img src="{{URL::to('img/zajeciadodatkowe.png')}}" alt="Image" height="200" width="200">

 <img href="{{URL::asset('img/zajeciadodatkowe.png')}}" alt="Image" height="200" width="200">

 <img src="{{URL::asset('img/zajeciadodatkowe.png')}}" alt="Image" height="200" width="200">

 <img href="{{asset('img/zajeciadodatkowe.png')}}" alt="Image" height="200" width="200">

 <img src="{{asset('img/zajeciadodatkowe.png')}}" alt="Image" height="200" width="200">
```

This problem occured when I put the laravel app onto development server.
Someone has any suggestions?

Comment: you should use `img src`, but what the source looks like when you write `{{URL::asset('img/zajeciadodatkowe.png')}}`. try to echo that expression to see if it really links to an existing image resource?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [`asset()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/helpers#method-asset) helper:

```
<img src="{{ asset('img/zajeciadodatkowe.png') }}">
```

And make sure the `zajeciadodatkowe.png` image is in `public/img` directory.

Comment: Yes, your solution works, anyway the problem was that the file was named zajeciadodatkowe.PNG and not zajeciadodatkowe.png. Thank you for your effort.